# tokio_core::net::UdpCodec with lifetime on associated type

Tags: rust, lifetime, mdns, rust-tokio

I am trying to implement a `tokio_core::net::UdpCodec` which create a `dns_parser::Packet` from the dns_parser crate. The implementation currently look like this:

```
pub struct MdnsCodec;

impl UdpCodec for MdnsCodec {
    type In = dns_parser::Packet;
    type Out = (SocketAddr, dns_parser::Builder);

    fn decode(&mut self, addr: &SocketAddr, buf: &[u8]) -> io::Result<Self::In> {
        Ok(dns_parser::Packet::parse(buf).unwrap())
    }

    fn encode(&mut self, (addr, builder): Self::Out, into: &mut Vec<u8>) -> SocketAddr {
        let packet_data = builder.build().unwrap();
        into.extend(&packet_data);
        addr
    }
}
```

The definition of [dns_parser::Packet](https://docs.rs/dns-parser/0.7.1/dns_parser/struct.Packet.html) is:

```
pub struct Packet<'a> {
    pub header: Header,
    pub questions: Vec<Question<'a>>,
    pub answers: Vec<ResourceRecord<'a>>,
    pub nameservers: Vec<ResourceRecord<'a>>,
    pub additional: Vec<ResourceRecord<'a>>,
    pub opt: Option<OptRecord<'a>>,
```

}

This fails to compile with:

```
error[E0106]: missing lifetime specifier
  --> src/main.rs:18:15
   |
18 |     type In = dns_parser::Packet;
   |               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected lifetime parameter

error: aborting due to previous error
```

The problem is I can't figure out what to add as a lifetime! I assume Packet needs to have the same lifetime as the buf argument. But I can't figure out how to express this properly myself.

I have uploaded a nonworking example to github:
https://github.com/Fulkerson/mdnsfuturestest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a tricky one. As far as I can tell the only way to get this to work is using Rust nightly (`rustup toolchain install nightly` and `rustup default nightly`) and using the nightly feature `generic_associated_types`. The reason is that Associated Types (like `type In`) weren't originally allowed to be Generics or to have any type/lifetime arguments.

```
#![feature(generic_associated_types)]

// ...includes...

pub struct MdnsCodec;

impl UdpCodec for MdnsCodec {
    type In<'a> = dns_parser::Packet<'a>;
    // ...rest of impl...
}

fn main() {
    // ...code...
}
```

There are of course the usual issues that arise with using prerelease software, for example that any unstable features you use could change at any time without warning.